# ConstPtr NULL with waitForMessage

Tags: ros, shared-ptr, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I have a function which is supposed to just get one message from a topic, the function looks like this:

```
std::vector<my_msgs::Person> getPersonList()
{   
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Duration four_seconds(4.0);
    
    my_msgs::PersonListConstPtr person_list = ros::topic::waitForMessage<my_msgs::PersonList>(
            "/my_world/persons_available",
            n, four_seconds);
    std::vector<my_msgs::Person> person_vector;
    person_vector = person_list->persons;
    return person_vector;
}
```

Whereas PersonList.msg is:

```
Person[] persons
```

And Person.msg something like:

```
string name
int age
...
```

Now when I call the function, the behavior is rather erratic. Sometimes I get the correct results for the first call(s) but after some time I get a  `Assertion 'px != 0' failed`.
Googling around told me that the shared_ptr PersonListConstPtr is NULL. And indeed when I do:

```
if(person_list != NULL)
        person_vector = person_list->persons;
```

My program is not crashing, but instead nothing happens, because apparently my pointer is always NULL.

Now, the topic is correct, it is published and everything. I have the suspicion that the original pointer is still active and that I can't get hold on it anymore after returning.
Can someone help me what to do? I am not very familliar with those `shared_ptr`. I already tried to `get()` the pointer but got a segmentation fault.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229914/constptr-null-with-waitformessage/) by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2016-03-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on 2016-03-23**:
Strangely, it worked when I use the function that does not require NodeHandle and Duration. If someone comes up with a solution with a timeout (becuase it is clearly not waiting the time I set), I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could it be that your pointer `person_list` is simply set to NULL when waitForMessage times out after the duration you specified as parameter (4 sec)? See [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/73258/detecting-timeout-from-waitformessage/).

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on 2016-03-23**:
I now set the timeout to 10 seconds and it definitely returns earlier with a NULL object. Whereas the first call always works.

**Comment by [niedzviedz](https://answers.ros.org/users/71812/niedzviedz/) on 2021-03-11**:
Same issue here. Sometimes it returns an empty pointer. Have you found the source of this problem?